# TortoiseHg hangs pulling from server over ssh

Tags: ssh, mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a linux box being used as my hg server (although it's not running any explicit server other than sshd). I used to be able to interact with this server normally on windows via TortoiseHg but sometime in the past couple weeks that broke. The only significant change I can recall during that time is a general update of the server but nothing specific to any of the repos.

Running from the command line I get:

```
>hg --debug incoming
running "TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 hg@server "hg -R repo_dir/repo serve --stdio"
sending hello command
sending between command
```

I also tried going directly through putty's plink with no success.

```
>hg --debug incoming
running "c:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe" -ssh hg@server "hg -R repo_dir/repo serve --stdio"
sending hello command
sending between command
```

Testing plink directly indicates that it works, though.

```
>"c:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink" hg@server which ssh
hg@server's password:
/usr/bin/ssh
```

How do I figure out why I can't access this server from windows anymore?

Comment: is the ssh agent up and running, thus supplying the required credentials?

Comment: You mean on the Windows machine? It is possible to log in to this server via password only, which is the way it was done before (and how the login on the last block of code was done)

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm surprised by your unsuccessful login in Plink (I expected password request), but it's correct behavior for **windowless TortoisePlink** (you have to enter password in window, which TortoisePlink can't create)
2. Because TortoisePlink and Plink are in common the same, you can (have) to use the same command-line options in both. For user/pass interacitve authoriration I see at least 2 possible ways to change current `SSH command` in THG settings

From [Using the command-line connection tool Plink](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html)

> -load sessname  Load settings from saved session
>
> -pw passw login with specified password

`sessname` is previously created Putty-session, in which you have password stored

In `-pw` you'll enter password directly in command-line (insecure)